# annoying parameter error for polylineWithCoordinates

Tags: ios, swift, mkpolyline

I am trying to initialize a polyline from a 2 element `CLLocationCoordinate2D` array called coordarray and the number 2, using this code:

```
self.line = MKPolyline.polylineWithCoordinates(coordarray,2)
```

however I am getting an error saying

> Cannot invoke 'polylineWithCoordinates' with an argument list of type
>   ([CLLocationCoordinate2D],Int)

I have checked the docs, and it seems that I have passed the correct parameter list, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

That error message is very misleading - checking the documentation for [MKPolyline](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/index.html) there isn't actually a static method called `polylineWithCoordinates` for Swift, you may be looking at the Objective-C version of the documentation*. Perhaps you meant to use:

> ```
> convenience init!(coordinates coords: UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>,
>                   count count: Int)
> ```

In which case I believe your code needs to be:

```
// Note - coordarray is declared as var
var coordarray = // ...

self.line = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordarray, count: 2)
```

Here's a link detailing more about adding an `MKPolyline` overlay: http://mobiletoolworks.com/adding-a-mkpolyline-overlay-using-swift-to-an-ios-mapkit-map/

*To change the documentation from displaying Objective-C to Swift, there's a control in the top-right corner of the page:

[image]

Comment: Hey, what happened to your link?  Thanks!